# How can I quickly calculate particle attributes?

Tags: particle-system

Firstly can I say I have only a very basic knowledge of maths / three.js / webgl, so sorry if some of these questions sound daft!

Anyway, I want to make a particle system - something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwCAsyiYimY

As I make it I realise that I have lots of questions!

I have created a particle(s), that has velocity and direction etc..

These get pushed to a THREE.PointCloud

With each render loop, I loop through each particle in the point cloud and alter the velocity / direction,

```
//move the particles
        for( var i = 0; i < _this.pool.length; i++ ){

            //direction is the mouse pos
            var dir = mousePos;

            //var dir =  new THREE.Vector3(500, 500, 0);   

            dir.sub( _this.pool[i].position).normalize().multiplyScalar(0.10);

            //acceleration
            _this.pool[i].force = dir;

            //velocity
            _this.pool[i].velocity.add( _this.pool[i].force );

            //position
            _this.pool[i].position.add( _this.pool[i].velocity ); 
        }
```

I guess this is all ok , untill I start to add lots of particles, 10000's or particles looped through each render loop, starts to slow things down.

I guess Im doing something wrong as i can hear  the fans on my mac starting to blow.

At the moment I'm not using any shaders.

Is there a way to get the calculations, positioning, velocity etc onto the GPU as I would imaging that would be quicker, than using JS to calcuate this?

Comment: Search gpgpu. Also look at the flocking birds example, and google chrome experiments.

Comment: Hi Jared, thats for your reply, found some nice things here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4069 looks like you can add positioning to a vertex shader.